# Heroku deploy angular application, build success but Application error?

Tags: angular, heroku

Application error

2021-10-10T05:13:52.496118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dashboard-agri.herokuapp.com request_id=03476fb8-2620-4c0a-9b5f-9588550b653f fwd="103.70.199.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. That error message doesn't tell us anything useful. Please [edit] your answer to include _all_ the error messages, and a [mre] of the code that generates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.removed the package-lock.json
2. inside package.json change npm start to node server.js
 ie: {
      "npm start" : "node server.js"
        }
```

before changing change the version number its working

Comment: I love you man. You just saved me from hours of debugging.